# How to apply an effect of white lines crossed to a div with css

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How to apply an effect of white lines crossed to a div with css as shown in the following image link:

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_9266640efecto.jpg

Comment: By using a background-image, you can found them typing `backgrond patterns` on google.

Comment: see this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/ but check if your required browser supports css3 http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp